# Compute $\Pr(U_1>60\mid U_1+U_2+\cdots+U_{20}=1800)$ for $(U_i)$ i.i.d. uniform on $\{0,1,\ldots,120\}$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Say I have 20 discrete uniform i.i.d random variables $U_i$ with
$$U_i\sim U(0, 120)$$
and I am told that:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{20}U_i = 1800$$
I want to know the probability that one of the realisations is above its mean given this information, or in other words  $U_j > 60$ for any $j\in\{1, 2, \cdots, n\}$ ? That is, what is:
$$Pr\{U_j > 60 | \sum_{i=1}^{20}U_i = 1800\}$$

Comment: $U_i\sim (0,120)$ means a discrete distribution where $U_i$ is equally likely to be $1,2,3\ldots 119?$

Comment: I actually meant between 0 and 120 inclusive - apologies for unclear notation.